# How much math do we need to prove all simple numeric identities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, axioms, elementary-functions

Consider real numeric expressions build only from integers, operators $+,-,\times,/$ and taking a positive expression to a power (no variables involved), e.g.
$$\frac{2}{7},\ 2^{1/2},\ \sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt{11}},\ 2^{\sqrt{3}},\ ...$$
Now we can write identities between such expressions that are either true, e.g. $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}=1+\sqrt{2}$, or false, e.g. $\frac{3}{5}=\frac{2}{7}$.

> Is it possible to prove all such true identities and disprove all false identities using only usual "high-school" algebra rules?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_high_school_algebra_problem

Comment: @LordSoth If I understand correctly, Tarski's problem asks about identities that may involve variables.

Comment: When I first read the question, I thought you were looking for the variable form. I also wasn't sure at which "level" you were asking the question, so I thought maybe you have not heard about Tarski's problem that I shared above. So you are just looking at identities only involving numerals, no variables? For example, like "Prove that $4+1 = 3+2$?"

Comment: @LordSoth Yes, only numerals and 5 operators (provided that we do not raise a non-positive expression to a power).

Comment: How could taking an irrational power even be _expressed_ "using only usual 'high-school' algebra rules"$\hspace{.02 in}$? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer $2^{\sqrt{3}}=2^{3^{1/2}}$

Comment: I love the question, but I think you also have to answer: can we decide, using high school rules, whether or not an expression $e$ so constructed is positive? (Thereby allowing us to safely raise $e$ to a previously constructed number). So to even express the questions rigorously is non-trivial (its still a great question though).

Comment: @user18921 You may assume that all identities you have to (dis-)prove obey the rules.

Comment: I am not even sure that $ZFC$ axioms are sufficient to settle all such questions. We do not yet know if $2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{1/2}}}}}}$ is an integer.

Comment: I don't know why you've termed this "all simple numeric identities", when a natural language use of such a phrase preferably will imply many more identities.  You can't prove identities like min(2, 3)=2, or identities involving say a function like #, where #(2, 3)=4, #(x, y)=+(x, y) otherwise, which implies identities like [(2#3)+4]=8.

Comment: How would you know such an identity true if you couldn't prove it using such rules?  Also, how do you have those "high school algebra" rules without variables?  How do you know you haven't used variables (or something similar) when finding those identities?  How do you have the logical notions which underpin the use of those "high school algebra rules" *which do use variables, but consistently disallow variables for the identities?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The rules could be formulated using as axiom schemata containing metavariables that you would have to fill in with variable-free expressions every time you invoke an axiom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, this is an open problem. It might be the case that even $ZFC$ axioms are not sufficient to settle all such questions, or that the problem is even undecidable (although it seems unlikely). The main issue that we know very little about behavior of repeated exponentiation. For example, it is unknown if the following number is an integer:
$$2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{1/2}}}}}}$$
Personally, I expect that there are no surprises to be discovered in the repeated exponentiation, that this number will eventually be proved to be transcendental, and that there are no unexpected identities in your class of expressions that could not be explained using only "high-school" algebra rules. But these are only conjectures.

Comment: I like your conjectures.

Answer (score -5):

I'll answer no.

Suppose you could prove all identities using such rules.  Then there could get written  some infinite list of *all* such identities (you could enumerate all such identities by a characteristic function which returns "true" for each true identity and "false" for each false identity).  But, that would imply you could have a bijection between the set of all natural numbers and *all* of those identities.  So, you could encode all of those identities via the natural numbers.  Included in this list identities is all identities involving real numbers including pi=pi, e=e, sqrt(2)=sqrt(2).  That set of identities clearly has the same cardinality as the set of all real numbers.  But, there does not exist any bijection between the set of real numbers and the set of natural numbers.  So there does not exist any bijection between the set of all natural numbers and that of all such "high-school" algebra identities.  Therefore, you cannot prove "all such true identities and disprove all false identities using only usual "high-school" algebra rules".

Comment: The (hypothetical) list does *not* include all identities involving real numbers. e.g. $\pi=\pi$ is not identity involving `real numeric expressions build only from integers, operators +,−,×,/ and taking a positive expression to a power`.

Comment: The set of identities in question is countable and recursively enumerable.

Comment: @Hurkyl Strictly speaking, we do no know if $\pi$ is expressible in this way. But you are right, it does not include all real numbers.

Comment: @Vladimir: To be picky, "$\pi$" is not an expression of the form, although there may be other forms expressible in this way that have the same value as $\pi$.

Comment: @Hurkyl You're right, but the list can get used to form sequences of pairs of identities like the following: [(2=2, 3=3),  (2.7=2.7, 2.8=2.8), (2.71=2.71, 2.72=2.72), (2.718=2.718, 2.719=2.719), (2.7182=2.7182, 2.7183=2.7183), (2.71828=2.71828, 2.71829=2.71829), ...], and in general sequences of pairs of identities that get closer and closer to any real number can get found.  So, how does it matter that the (hypothetical) list doesn't include all identities involving real numbers?

Comment: Because such a list can be countable. To wit, each of your examples is given by pair of rational numbers (although you use a very small fraction of such pairs), and there is only countably many of those.

Comment: I don't think algebraic identities include limits.